# any widget like webview of android in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hi I want to hit one URL that show an image in half page and in remaining half page one table. In android I use webview for that. But how to do that in jquery mobile? Is there is any widget like webview of android? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.   My current html file is as:

```
<div data-role="page" id="findusPage" data-theme="e">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Find Us</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">    
<p>
Apex International Hotel, Edinburgh<br/>
31-35 Grassmarket<br/>
Edinburgh<br/>
EH1 2HS<br/>
Scotland<br/>
</p>

<p>
<img src="http://10.22.32.121/charts/mobilechart.asp">
</p>

<p>
<a data-role="button" id="drivingButton" data-theme="a">Get driving directions</a>
</p>

</div>

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div>
```

But it doesnt show image

Comment: If I enter any other image path as "http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/00ak1o6usanngu0laxne.jpg" instead of "http://10.22.32.121/charts/mobilechart.asp" then it show image. But in my orignal URL image is not visible, and if I hit orignal URL on my desktop browser then it show the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the answer instead of img tag iframe tag solve my problem.